# Dynamically loading SWFs into a container

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I'm writing a preview site that will load SWFs/images from a URL into a preview pane. However, the primary problem I'm running into is actually loading these SWFs. It seems that the object/embed tags require width/height attributes. I will not know the exact size of these SWFs; in fact, I will know absolutely nothing about them.

What I'm asking is, what is the best way to load in these SWFs? Is there a library that exists to do this? Or do I need to do it myself? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Generaly, swf files can stretch to fit with the screen, so it doesn't matter the width/height of the swf files, for a preview you can try 80x60 (10% of usual screen size)
think to use SWFobject.js !!

Comment: But I don't want them to fill the screen, I want to actually have an accurate preview.

Comment: That's why i said use "80x60" for a preview it's a good size, no ?

Comment: Oh, I think you're misunderstanding me; I want the preview to be actual size. This isn't a thumbnail preview, I mean I want the user to be able to preview something before using it.

Comment: @Jake King - but "what" defines accurate preview or actual size?  For example, a typical JPEG image has no "actual size".  It can be scaled up or down in any proportion or it can be displayed without scaling at whatever screen resolution the viewer has (which can be different for every viewer).

Comment: @jfriend00 - The "Actual size" is the size defined in the publish settings of the SWF. Aka the size the SWF is actually meant to be displayed at.

Comment: From what I've read, you can specify in the publish settings that you only want the movie displayed at actual size (no scaling).  From a forum discussion: "If you want a fixed size then set the Dimensions: option in the Publish Settings to "Match Movie". This will keep your Flash movie at the same size on all browser windows."

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load a swf inside of another swf (so the user doesn't get the actual location of the inner swf) then you could take a look at [SWFLoader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/SWFLoader.html)

Comment: This could be used for something like showing a movie preview or something like that